# How to create a list type View to fetch all the records from DB using spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

Suggest steps to create a list page using spring boot.
I have already fetched a single record using a jsp page but could not fetch any more.
code is as below.

```
<body>

   <div class="table-responsive-sm">          
  <table class="table table-dark table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Employee ID</th>
        <th>First name</th>
        <th>Last name</th>
        <th>Designation</th>
        <th>E-mail</th>
        <th>Mobile</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>${employee.id}</td>
        <td>${employee.fname}</td>
        <td>${employee.lname}</td>
        <td>${employee.designation}</td>
        <td>${employee.email}</td>
        <td>${employee.mobile}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: You can loop over your data to display them in your JSP

Answer (score 1):

Let assume you use the *JSTL* tags. So you can loop over your records using the tag `<c:forEach> </c:forEach>`.

Let assume the variable *employees* contains all your data. So, your code will look like:

```
<%@ taglib uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix = "c" %>

<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Some codes here -->
</head>

<body>

   <div class="table-responsive-sm">          
  <table class="table table-dark table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Employee ID</th>
        <th>First name</th>
        <th>Last name</th>
        <th>Designation</th>
        <th>E-mail</th>
        <th>Mobile</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <c:forEach var="employee" items="${employees}">
      <tr>
        <td>${employee.id}</td>
        <td>${employee.fname}</td>
        <td>${employee.lname}</td>
        <td>${employee.designation}</td>
        <td>${employee.email}</td>
        <td>${employee.mobile}</td>
      </tr>
    </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```